# How to query - Should not contain

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to figure, how can I create query which shows all the results from where clauses but do not include one email address, in the result output:

```
select * from [dbo].[UserDetails] u join [dbo].[Subscriptions] s on u.uID =   s.sUID 
where  s.[sPExpiryDate]>= getdate()  or s.[sExpiryDate] >= getdate() or    [sTExpiryDate] >= getdate()
and (s.[sB_All] = '1' or s.[sB_All] <> '1') or [sStories_Only] = 1
and u.uEmailAddress not in ('sample@.gmail.com')
and s.sPID = 163 order by u.uEmailAddress asc
```

I would like to the above query to output all the data but exempt the record, which contains the email address = sample@.gmail.com

when I execute the above query, the output still shows a record with the following email = sample@.gmail.com.  am I missing something?

as reference, this what my sample@gmail.com record looks like int the dataset:

```
email               sPExpiryDate    sExpiryDate                      sTExpiryDate
sample@.gmail.com   NULL            2016-04-11 00:00:00.000         2012-03-03  00:00:00.000
```

Please advice further. thanks

Comment: Think about speaking in English. "I'd like ham and eggs or toast." Does that mean you want `ham and (eggs or toast)` or `(ham and eggs) or toast`? See http://databases.aspfaq.com/general/why-do-i-get-weird-results-when-using-both-and-and-or-in-a-query.html

Comment: Is `(s.[sB_All] = '1' or s.[sB_All] <> '1')` a sneaky way of writing `s.[sB_All] is not NULL`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue here might be operator precedence. If you wrap the first line of the WHERE clause in parentheses, does that give you what you want?

```
WHERE (s.[sPExpiryDate]>= getdate() or s.[sExpiryDate] >= getdate() or [sTExpiryDate] >= getdate())
AND ...
```

What's probably happening is that one of those first expressions is evaluating to TRUE. That would short circuit the rest of the checks.

Just noticed that you have another set of expressions that are OR'd. You may need to reorganize those as well.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I already tried the above query, by adding parentheses around the first where clause, but it does not show me the correct number of output, it should give me 375 (excluding the email record), but when I add the parentheses, it shows me 370 output.

Comment: I don't think you should need a nested query. Take a look at that link Aaron provided above. Also, make sure that you're handling that middle check around sB_All and sStories_only correctly. You have ORs mixed in there as well which could potentially be causing you problems.

Comment: @user3070072: Please read the answer carefully. It mentions that you've got another set of predicates connected with ORs. Take a closer look. Take Aaron's comment into account as well. Specify parentheses in places where a confusion is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want. You would have to say what you want filter and what you don't want in your question. I took the best guess I could.

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[UserDetails] u
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Subscriptions] s ON u.uID = s.sUID
WHERE   u.uEmailAddress != 'sample@.gmail.com'
        AND s.sPID = 163
        AND
        (
            s.[sPExpiryDate] >= getdate()
            OR s.[sExpiryDate] >= getdate()
            OR [sTExpiryDate] >= getdate()
        )
        AND 
        (
        s.[sB_All] IS NOT NULL 
        OR [sStories_Only] = 1
        )
ORDER BY u.uEmailAddress ASC
```